# Tkinter Image transparency

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So I have 2 images that I would like to display on top of each other.
The image on top should have transparency so that the one on the bottom is visible.

Here is my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

face = Image.open("faces/face.gif")
eyes = Image.open("faces/eyes1.png")
face = face.convert("RGBA")
eyes = eyes.convert("RGBA")
facedatas = face.getdata()
eyesdatas = eyes.getdata()

newData = []
for item in eyesdatas:
    if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

eyes.putdata(newData)
eyes.save("eyes0.png", "PNG")

facepic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(face)
eyespic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(eyes)

label1 = Label(image=facepic)
label1.image = facepic
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

label2 = Label(image=eyespic)
label2.image = eyespic
label2.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

And here is what I get when I run it:

[image: Eyes]

When I would like to obtain this:

[image: face and eyes]

With the face in the bottom and the eyes on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, Label

root = Tk()

def RBGAImage(path):
    return Image.open(path).convert("RGBA")

face = RBGAImage("faces/face.gif")
eyes = RBGAImage("faces/eyes1.png")

face.paste(eyes, (0, 0), eyes)

facepic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(face)

label1 = Label(image=facepic)
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

I do not have both your source images, so I can not be sure it will work with them. Please provide the originals of both if there is any issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Image.alpha_composite` to create a new composited image.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, Label

root = Tk()

def RBGAImage(path):
    return Image.open(path).convert("RGBA")

face = RBGAImage("faces/face.gif")
eyes = RBGAImage("faces/eyes1.png")

c = Image.alpha_composite(face, eyes)

facepic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(c)

label1 = Label(image=facepic)
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```