# Tkinter Button Transparency

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some code that has the image of a cookie inside of a button, the problem is that when this is run with the background image, it makes this effect:

[image]

How do I make the rest of the button around the cookie (which is already transparet) also transparent? Thanks.

Comment: Is the image just the cookie or does it have white around it?

Comment: With seeing your code, it is hard to tell you how to change it.  You probably have to tell tk to expand the image and fill the button.  Try looking at the online references given in the first section of the tkinter doc.

Comment: Is the picture a gif?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the background of the button to the background colour of the window. This doesn't work on a mac mind you. All widgets are essentially rectangular so there is no way to have a picture shaped button without the area around it being there.

Comment: What happens if your background is an image? I mean this might work for static backgrounds but for any real application this isn't a real option.

Answer (score 0):

This can make the white part transparent [Tkinter Image transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904942/tkinter-image-transparency)
but the background of the button remains. 
Im still trying to find the solution to that. Hope it helps.