# How do i set text background transparent in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tryed in many ways but i dont find solution for the problem
i want to put the text background transparent

#Text where the background is black

```
Download=Label(root,text="00",font="calibri 40 bold",bg="#000000",fg="white")
Download.place(x=320,y=261,anchor="center")
```

i want to turn black background to transparent background

i want to turn black text background to transparent background

Comment: What library are you using? Maybe `Label` accepts an `alpha` or `transparency` parameter?

Comment: im using, tkinter, threading, PIL, speedtest

Comment: You may have an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904942/tkinter-image-transparency

Comment: it didnt work because its a text and not an image

Comment: tkinter `Label` does not support transparent background.

Comment: but is there a way to do it whitout label?

Comment: You can use `Canvas` as the background and use the canvas drawing function `.create_text(...)` to draw the text on it instead of using `Label`.

Comment: can un make an exemple pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkinter `Label` does not support transparent. But you can use `Canvas` as the background and its drawing function `.create_text(...)` to draw some text on it with transparency.

Below is a simple example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

# background image
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="images/background.png")
canvas.create_image(400, 300, image=img)

# draw text
canvas.create_text(320, 261, text="00", font="calibri 40 bold", fill="white")

root.mainloop()
```

And the result:

[image]